# Lubuntu alongside Kubuntu - doubled up apps

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu, and on top of that `lubuntu-desktop` as I need to use the Lubuntu environment for testing some things. Now when I log into Kubuntu there seem to be some Lubuntu applications floating around that are at best using up resources and at worst interfering.

I ended up wth two screen-lockers (so need to log in twice to get back to a session) and the IBus keyboard layout app which interferes with the Kubuntu one. There may be other processes that are doubling up so I wonder what is the best way of preventing this doubling up in a global fashion?

I disabled light-locker on kubuntu using light-locker-settings and now the light-locker process does not show up and I uninstalled IBus, but I still run the risk of missing some processes.

Comment: Depending on why you need Lubuntu, could you try removing `lubuntu-desktop` and installing plain LXDE Desktop?

Comment: Good point. I will try this.